# ECS Blue/Green Deployment with CodeDeploy - Autoscaling Instances Number

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, blue-green-deployment

I'm using ECS (on EC2) with blue/green deployment powered by AWS CodeDeploy.

After creating a new task definition, and updating the service to use it, a new deployment on AWS CodeDeploy starts. However, the new task is not able to run on my service due to this error:
`service my-service-dev was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements...`

I understand that the current instances used by the cluster cannot run the new task. If I manually add new instances, by increasing the minimal capacity in the auto-scaling group of the cluster, then the deployment takes place successfully.

I wanted to know if there is a way to make this happen automatically. Increasing the maximum capacity (in the same place) doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Exactly same issue here. Did you solved it?

Comment: Not really. I found out that a possible solution would be to use Fargate (though there are other considerations for that).

Comment: Right. If use fargate, it solved perfectly. (Because fargate do not need ec2 instance) If you found any solution about this, please notice it through the comments. Thanks.